# Can I have more than one native activity in android

Tags: android-ndk

I'm currently new to the android native development kit (NDK). Is it possible to have more than one native activity in a purely native application with intents to switch between activities (a similar way to that of the SDK)?

Comment: You will need some little Java to have it working. Your two activities will both **extend** the stock NativeActivity.

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks for the advice